# Join three CTEs - I am trying to make join between 3 CTEs( cte_1.InvoiceDate11=cte_2.InvoiceDate11=cte_3.EndDate11 ).Could you please help me with it?

Tags: sql

I am trying to make join between 3 CTEs (cte_1.InvoiceDate11 = cte_2.InvoiceDate11 = cte_3.EndDate11).

Could you please help me with it?

```
with cte_1 as( )

      select InvoiceDate11,
       COUNT(ContractId)as_number_of_Customers
      From  cte_1 
      where ROW_NUM=1 and InvoiceDate11>'2019-01'
      group by InvoiceDate1



with cte_2 as( )

      Select InvoiceDate11, 
      COUNT(InvoiceDate11) as New_customers From cte_2
      where ROW_NUM=1 and FirstInvoiceDate1=1 
       group by  InvoiceDate2



with cte_3 as(    )

    Select EndDate11,
    COUNT(EndDate11) as #ofcancellation
    From  cte_3
    Where ROW_NUM=1   
    AND EndDate11 IS NOT NULL 
    GROUP BY EndDate11
```

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? *SQL* is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... features like this are often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** you're using.... (please update tags accordingly)

Comment: @SimonSoltanian . . . You should ask a *new* question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you are trying to do.  Your code as written simply does not work, because the ctes are referring to themselves and columns are not defined.

Comment: please write a summarized title and put the rest of the explanation in the body.

Answer (score 1):

First, please mention your dbms name with version for better suggestion.

You can declare multiple common table expression separated by comma in a single statement and then combine them with joins.

You can follow below syntax:

```
with cte_1 as( ),
cte_2 as( ),
cte_3 as( )
select * from cte_1 inner join cte_2 
     on cte_1.InvoiceDate11 = cte_2.InvoiceDate11
inner join cte_3
     on cte_2.InvoiceDate11 = cte_3.EndDate11
```

Revised answer:

```
with cte_1 as( ),
    cte_2 as( ),
    cte_3 as( )

      select cte_1.InvoiceDate11, COUNT(cte_1.ContractId)as number_of_Customers,
      COUNT(cte_2.InvoiceDate11) as New_customers ,
      COUNT(cte_3EndDate11) as number_of_cancellation
      From  cte_1 left join cte_2
                       on cte_1.InvoiceDate11 = cte_2.InvoiceDate11 and cte_1.ROW_NUM=1 and cte_2.ROW_NUM=1 and cte_1.InvoiceDate11>'2019-01' and cte_2.FirstInvoiceDate1=1
                  left join cte_3
                       on cte_1.InvoiceDate11 = cte_3.EndDate11 and cte_3.ROW_NUM=1 and EndDate11 IS NOT NULL 
      where  InvoiceDate11>'2019-01'
      group by InvoiceDate1
```

Comment: Depending on the **concrete** RDBMS, you **must not** repeat the `with` keyword ..... use `with cte_1 as (.....), cte_2 as (......), cte_3 as (.....) select .....`

Comment: But after CTEs    with cte_1(.....) , with cte_2 as(.... ), with cte_3 as(......) I have another thing to get them.

Comment: @marc_s thanks a lot. It was a mistake. I have revised my anwer.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur thank you very much. Could you please let me know how can I join them?

Comment: @SimonSoltanian I have revised my answer. Assumed that you want left joins.